# creating Session.Timeout in web.config and global.asax

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In web.config, I had this code -

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="true" timeout="30" />
```

How do I link this `session.timeout` in `web.config` to `Session_End` in `global.asax`?

Comment: Did you look this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikhiln/archive/2007/06/21/detecting-session-timeout-in-asp-net-2-0-web-applications.aspx ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use global.asax's session end event to remove the unexpectedly disconnected user :

```
void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs E) {
// Clean up session resources
```

}

but beware, session doesn't end when the user closes his browser or his connection lost. It ends when the session timeout reached.

Comment: Thank you. But can I have the coding to place there?

Answer (score 0):

The [Session.TimeOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525473%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) property should give you this value.